# How to structure backlog and ceremonies around a team with separate skillsets working from a backlog which is not directly connected

Tags: scrum, scrum-master, backlog, sprint-backlog

I have a team of engineers who are building a data intelligence capability for the organisation.

As such the team members are I-shaped and the work is I-shaped i.e. 1 team member can only work from 1 of the categories below. The work in each category does support the other categories in some way but its not directly linked like on for example a project building an iOS app.

I am trying to figure out how best to structure the backlog, the team and the scrum ceremonies.

The different categories of work/roles on the team are:

- Front end type work (2 team members)
- Architecture type work (1 team member)
- ITOps/infrastructure type work (1 team member)

My question is should we all be doing planning sprints together, stand-ups and retrospectives etc or how should we set things up?

Comment: Why do you want to use Scrum? If you aren't trying to solve a common problem with a dedicated team, it seems like Scrum is a poor fit

Comment: That is the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: **You don't.**

Scrum framework is a *tool* for a *purpose*. As any tool, you should know when to use it... and your case is hard to be one. It *could* be one if the members are willing to go beyond their siloes of knowledge, but it'll be challenging to have a proper Scrum from day one if you have clear categories within the team.

Now, **what *could* you do**?

There are other agile frameworks who could fit better for your case, as Kanban for instance. Kanban might be a better fit as it's broadly known and more fluid to have consistent work done across the different team members. You can also use some of the Scrum ceremonies, *so long they are helpful*. You can check for an [extensive list of agile methods in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development#Agile_software_development_methods).

How to find the best framework to fit your purpose? **Experiment**. You can even start applying Scrum for a few iterations, check the team perception at the retro, and propose other frameworks (or variances of known frameworks). Just do not try to make your team to fit a framework because "it's the best framework". It simply won't work.

you have to ***explore* for the best framework - *for your team***.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Other than Kanban and Scrum. Are there any other frameworks I should explore / experiment with?

Comment: Hi @user32613, just expanded the answer adding wikipedia link.